# How to pass params in url to another resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am developing a kind of job board, where I have a "page" called 'jobdetails' with job details ('jobdetails' displays openings resources) job with apply button that should redirect to 'jobapplications' "page" where the jobseeker can upload his cv (not yet implemented) and save opening_id.

I tried many ways but still not working.

I said I want to pass params with url but i'am open with other ways, model or controller.

thanks.

Edit: I Am able to save a record but opening_id remains blank...

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
    devise_for :jobseekers, controllers: { registrations: "jobseekers/registrations", sessions: "jobseekers/sessions" }
  resources :companypics
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
  resources :openings 
  resources :jobapplications
  resources :companies
  resources :locations
  resources :timesheets
  resources :expenses
  resources :jobdescriptions
  resources :jobdetails 
  root :to => 'dashbords#index'
  end
```

```html
class JobapplicationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_jobseeker!

  layout 'apply'
def applyparam
  @opening = Opening.find(params[:opening])

end

  def index
    @jobapplications = Jobapplication.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @jobapplication = Jobapplication.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @jobapplication = current_jobseeker.jobapplications.create(jobapplication_params)
    @jobapplication.save
    redirect_to new_jobapplication_path
  end

  def update
    @jobapplication.update(jobapplication_params)
  end

  def destroy
    @jobapplication.destroy
  end

  private
    

    def jobapplication_params
      params.require(:jobapplication).permit(:opening_id, :jobseeker_id, )
    end
end
```

```html
class JobdetailsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'apply'

  def show
    @jobdetail = Opening.find_by_applyjobid(params[:applyjobid])
    @logo = current_user.company.logo.url

  end
  end
```

```html
Jobdetails Show

<div class='login-container'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4'>
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='.col-xs-6 .col-md-4'>
          <div class='row'>
                   <h1>
              <strong><%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.job_title %></strong>
            </h1>
            <br/>
            <b>Company:   </b>
            <br/>
            <%= @jobdetail.company.company_name %>
            <br> </br>
            <%= image_tag @logo  %>     
            <br>
            <b>Job Location:   </b>
            <br/>
            <%= @jobdetail.location.name %> <%= @jobdetail.location.postalcode %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <b>Job salary:   </b>
            <br/>
            <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.rate_pay %>
            <br>
            <br/>
              <p class="jobsummary"><b>Job Summary:   </b>
                <br/>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.job_summary %></p>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.shift.blank? -%>
          <b>Job shift:   </b>
                <br/>
            <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.shift %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>
            <br>

            <b>Job requirements:   </b>
            <br/>

            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.job_duties.blank? -%>
               <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.job_duties %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>

            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.tasks.blank? -%>
            <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.tasks %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.job_duties.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.job_duties %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.responsibilities.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.responsibilities %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.results.blank? -%>

            <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.results %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.skills.blank? -%>

          <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.skills %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>

            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.knowledge.blank? -%>

          <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.knowledge %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>

            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.abilities.blank? -%>
          <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.abilities %>
            <br>
            <br/>
            <% end %>
            <br>

            <b>Education:   </b>
            <br/>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.education_and_training.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.education_and_training %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.qualifications.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.qualifications %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.license_certification.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.license_certification %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>
            <br>

            <b>Job environment:   </b>
            <br/>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.physical_requirement.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.physical_requirement %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.work_envir_condition.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.work_envir_condition %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.protective_clothing_and_devices_required.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.protective_clothing_and_devices_required %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.tools_or_equipment_required.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.tools_or_equipment_required %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>
            <br>

            <b>Benefits:   </b>
            <br/>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.benefits.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.benefits %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>
            <% if !@jobdetail.jobdescription.other_benefits.blank? -%>
                <%= @jobdetail.jobdescription.other_benefits %>
                <br>
                <br/>
            <% end %>

            <br>
            <br/>

            <%= link_to "Apply now", new_jobapplication_path(:opening => @jobdetail.id) %>
```

```html
<%= form_for (@jobapplication) do |f| %>
    <div class='login-container'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4'>
        <h1 class='text-center title'>Apply</h1>
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        <div class='form-group'>

          </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.hidden_field :opening %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
        <% end %>
        </form>
```

```html
class Jobapplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :opening

end
```

```html
create_table "jobapplications", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "opening_id"
    t.integer  "jobseeker_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

```html
Started POST "/jobapplications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-25 10:49:38 +0100
Processing by JobapplicationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"+0z1IIG0COeYZUQavPUZXu/5m316t9VrUs9eiOFrMjA=", "jobapplication"=>{"opening"=>"#<Opening:0x85cc
f80>"}, "commit"=>"Submit your timesheet"}
  Jobseeker Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "jobseekers".* FROM "jobseekers"  WHERE "jobseekers"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "jobseekers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: opening
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "jobapplications" ("created_at", "jobseeker_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-05-25 09:49:39.
818752"], ["jobseeker_id", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-05-25 09:49:39.818752"]]
   (131.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/jobapplications/new
Completed 302 Found in 591ms (ActiveRecord: 134.0ms)
```

Comment: In which action do you want to receive the parameter? And from where?

Comment: hi, From Jobdetails#show to jobapplication#new thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view change `opening` to `opening_id` :

```
<%= link_to "Apply now", new_jobapplication_path(opening_id: @jobdetail.id) %>
```

In you `new` action instantiate with the `opening_id` :

```
def new
  @jobapplication = Jobapplication.new(opening_id: params[:opening_id])
end
```

Comment: thanks again, but still param is missing or the value is empty: jobapplication

Comment: I sorted it out !! "def new
  @jobapplication = Jobapplication.new(:opening => params[:opening])
  end" I aso added "<%= hidden_field(:jobapplication, :opening, :value => params[:opening]) %> " thanks your help

Comment: Great... Never give up! :)